# Проблема с asyncio Python парсинг

Tags: python, asyncio

Необходимо спарсить некоторые данные с telegram, поэтому использую библиотеку Telethon.
Имеется код:

```
    load_numbers(filename_numbers) #Загрузка телефонов
    if(queue_entity.qsize()==0):
        load_excel(filename_excel)     #Загрузка Excel
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.set_debug(True)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(start_last("test_last"))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
            task.cancel()
            with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
                loop.run_until_complete(task)
    finally:
        loop.stop()
```

В этом участке кода я запускаю парсинг уже распределенных каналов (Распределенные это значит, что определенный канал будет парсить определенный клиент Telegram)

```
start_last("test_last")
```

использую в качестве заглушки, так как мне не нужно передавать какой либо параметр (по другому не знаю как, без входного параметра, loop не работает)

Если после этого участка кода ничего нет, то все работает нормально.
Но если у меня после него есть какой-либо код, например:

```
for number in numbers:
    #Проверяем есть ли уже созданные клиенты:
    try:
        print("Такой client уже есть:", client_dict[number])
    except KeyError:
        #Нету, значит создаем
        create_client(number)
```

То у меня кидает ошибку:

```
2019-03-01 00:21:27,928 INFO:Connecting to 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 660, in <module>
    print("Такой client уже есть:", client_dict[number])
KeyError: '776912989'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 663, in <module>
    create_client(number)
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 229, in create_client
    client = [TelegramClient(str(number), api_id, api_hash, proxy=proxy).start(), number]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 115, in start
    else self.loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 482, in run_until_complete
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop stopped before Future completed.')
RuntimeError: Event loop stopped before Future completed.
```

И я не могу разобраться почему выходит эта ошибка.
Если я вместо `loop.stop()` буду использовать `loop.close()`, то выкинет другую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 660, in <module>
    print("Такой client уже есть:", client_dict[number])
KeyError: '776912989'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 663, in <module>
    create_client(number)
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 229, in create_client
    client = [TelegramClient(str(number), api_id, api_hash, proxy=proxy).start(), number]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 115, in start
    else self.loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 460, in run_until_complete
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 377, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AuthMethods._start' was never awaited
2019-03-01 00:24:09,130 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<UpdateMethods._update_loop() running at C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py:213> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001F3C412F198>()]>>
2019-03-01 00:24:09,131 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<_send_loop() running at C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py:375> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001F3C412F9D8>()]>>
2019-03-01 00:24:09,131 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<_recv_loop() running at C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py:413> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001F3C412FCD8>()]>>
2019-03-01 00:24:09,131 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<Connection._send_loop() running at C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py:133> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001F3C412FE88>()]>>
2019-03-01 00:24:09,131 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<Connection._recv_loop() running at C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py:151> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001F3C412FC78>()]>>
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object _recv_loop at 0x000001F3C7047CA8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 413, in _recv_loop
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py", line 121, in recv
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\queues.py", line 169, in get
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 591, in call_soon
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 377, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
2019-03-01 00:24:09,131 ERROR:Unexpected exception in the send loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\queues.py", line 167, in get
    yield from getter
GeneratorExit

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py", line 133, in _send_loop
    self._send(await self._send_queue.get())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\queues.py", line 169, in get
    getter.cancel()  # Just in case getter is not done yet.
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 591, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 377, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object Connection._send_loop at 0x000001F3C7047D58>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py", line 143, in _send_loop
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py", line 92, in disconnect
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 591, in call_soon
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 377, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Помогите разобраться, мне необходимо будет потом запустить другой loop, а я с этой проблемой не могу разобраться.

Код функций:

```
async def start_last(text):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    initial_future = loop.create_future()
    initial_future.set_result(text)

    await crawl_last(initial_future)

async def crawl_last(text):
    futures = []
    test = await text #Заглушка
    # Пока очередь из entity не пуста
    print(queue_entity_last.qsize())
    while queue_entity_last.qsize() > 0:
        parameters = queue_entity_last.get_nowait()
        entity = parameters[0]
        phone = parameters[1]
        futures.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_entity(entity, client_dict[phone])))
    if futures:
        await asyncio.wait(futures)
```

Comment: проблема в функции create_client. loop закрывать и останавливать не нужно.

Comment: @eri спасибо, если хотите можете пометить как ответ

Answer (score 0):

Проверить наличие клиента можно намного проще и надёжнее:

```
if number not in client_dict:
    create_client(number)
```

Comment: проблема не в этом

Comment: У вас в корне обоих трейсбеков лежит исключение `KeyError`, которое может возникать только по одной причине.